# How to make MERGE serializable

Tags: oracle, merge, atomic

When doing concurrent `MERGE`s while every session uses a different value (shown as *** in the snippet below) for the primary key column `id`, everything is fine if I do it manually in 2 terminal sessions.

```
MERGE
 INTO x
   USING (SELECT *** as id FROM DUAL) MERGE_SRC
     ON (x.id = MERGE_SRC.id)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET val = val + 1 WHERE id = ***
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (***, 99);
COMMIT;
```

However, running a multi-threaded load test with 3 or more threads, I will relatively quickly run into **`ORA-08177 with locked table`**. Why is that? (And why is it non-deterministic in that it does not always happen when transactions overlap?)

The table was created using

```
create table x (id int primary key, val int);
```

*SQL Server* btw never throws exceptions with an equivalent MERGE statement, running the same experiment. That is even true when working on the same row simultaneously.

Is it because perhaps MERGE is **not atomic**, and the serializable mode runs **optimistically**, so that the race might only show with sufficient contention? Still, why does it happen **even when not working on the same row concurrently?**

Btw, my attempts to [fix this using the strictest lock available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922261) were unsuccessful. So any ideas on how to make this atomic are very much appreciated. It looks like relaxing the isolation level would rid me of the exception, but risk inconsistencies in case there turn out to be 2 updates on the same row (otherwise why would it balk in serializable mode in the first place).

Comment: have you tried an update and an insert in a single transaction instead of using merge ? (merge can be a very quarky creature ...).

Comment: You mean `update` and `if rowcount=0 then insert`? When in serializable mode, I guess I have to do a manual lock as well, right?

Comment: can you explain why you insist on using seralization ? if session A and B are executing roughly at the same time and you need each session to operate on the state that existed when the transaction began then serialization is enough. that's it's purpose.

Comment: Serialization is enough to make exceptions fly. However, I want my transactions to succeed while leaving a consistent state. When in *serializable mode*, it seems I have to use an unwieldy loop as suggested by @BobJarvis to get this to run, even though I never work on the same row in different sessions at the same time. Btw by 'serialization is enough' you mean to say 'serialization through the use of locks, without actually using the isolation mode *serializable*'. That would certainly make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception you're seeing is a direct consequence of using strict serialization. If you have more than one transaction active simultaneously, each started with SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE, when any one of them commits the others will get an ORA-08177. That's how strict serialization is enforced - the database throws an ORA-08177 in any session started with ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE if another transaction commits into a table which the serializable session needs. So, basically, if you really need strict serialization you have to handle the ORA-08177's intelligently, as in the following:

```
DECLARE
  bSerializable_trans_complete  BOOLEAN := FALSE;
  excpSerializable              EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(excpSerializable, -08177);
BEGIN
  <<SERIALIZABLE_LOOP>>
  WHILE NOT bSerializable_trans_complete
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

      MERGE ...; -- or whatever

      COMMIT;

      bSerializable_trans_complete := TRUE;  -- allow SERIALIZABLE_LOOP to exit
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN excpSerializable THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        CONTINUE SERIALIZABLE_LOOP;
    END;
  END LOOP;  -- SERIALIZABLE_LOOP
END;
```

Serialization is not magic, and it's not "free" (where "free" means "I as the developer don't have to do anything to make it work properly"). It requires more planning and work on the part of the developer to have it function properly, not less. Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for giving an example for an *optimistic concurrency loop*. I might settle for that in the end. However, it is not as easy as `when any one of [2 simultaneous transactions] commits the others will get an ORA-08177`. As I mentioned, when working on different rows, it works fine - oftentimes.

Comment: Accepting your answer, as it solves the 'how to make merge serializable' question. Wonder though why changes on different rows clash.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, the `SERIALIZABLE` mode works optimistically, in contrast to e.g. SQL Server, which does pessimistic locking in that mode. Which means that in the latter case you can even concurrently change the same row without running into exceptions.

Despite [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/consist.htm#CNCPT1320):

> Oracle Database permits a serializable transaction to **modify a row only if changes to the row made by other transactions were already committed when the serializable transaction began**. The database generates an error when a serializable transaction tries to update or delete data changed by a different transaction that committed after the serializable transaction began:

load testing showed that **exceptions may also get thrown when not working on the same row simultaneously**, although that is not guaranteed, in contrast to when working on the same row, which will always result in an `ORA-08177`.