# Serializable transactions not protecting me from double inserts

Tags: oracle, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

In my scenario, a process engine allows only one instance of a process execution to be run at the same time, refusing others. Since my application is planned to be deployed to clusters, it is important that decisions taken in a node reflect the global system status. I understand that there are plenties of ways to achieve my goal.

For that we are implementing a database lock leveraging standard ACID transactions. We have a table PROCESS_RUNS where we record current and historical executions. Better say: we use the history table as a shared lock mechanism, relying on the database to handle concurrency. Note: IDs are generated not by means of DB sequences

```
| ID | PROCESS_ID | STATUS  | START_TIME | END_TIME |
|----|------------|---------|------------|----------|
| 1  | PROCESS1   | RUNNING | --         | --       |
| 2  | PROCESS1   | OK      | --         | --       |
| 3  | PROCESS2   | RUNNING | --         | --       |
| 4  | PROCESS3   | KO      | --         | --       |
```

Only constraint here is that, given column PROCESS_ID, only one instance of each process may be in RUNNING status. The application handles all the logic (including node power failures) to keep the database consistent. In the example above, PROCESS1 and PROCESS2 are running, so a new instance of PROCESS3 or PROCESS4 can be inserted into running status, but the application must refuse to `INSERT` a new instance of PROCESS1.

Consider the following Hibernate code:

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public boolean checkNotRunningAndInsert(String processId, ProcessRun run)
{
    DetachedCriteria criteria = forClass(getEntityClass()).add(eq("processId", requireNonNull(processId, "processId is required")))//
                                                          .add(eq("status", ProcessRunStatus.RUNNING))//
                                                          .setProjection(rowCount());

    long activeCount = DataAccessUtils.longResult(getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria));

    if (activeCount == 0)
    {
        // OK, return
        getHibernateTemplate().save(requireNonNull(run, "run is required"));
        return true;
    }
    else if (activeCount == 1)
    {
        // OK, process running
        return false;
    }
    else // if (activeCount>1)
    {
        log.error("Looks like more than 1 instance of the process {} is running. This is a bug", processId);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The above code does the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PROCESS_RUNS WHERE PROCESS_ID = ? AND STATUS = 'RUNNING'
```

Then if there are no rows it will issue

```
INSERT INTO PROCESS_RUNS (....,STATUS,....) VALUES (...,'RUNNING',...)
```

Otherwise it returns with a `false`. In case the DBMS refuses to commit the transaction, a `PessimisticLockingFailureException` is issued by Spring's `@Transactional` and handled in my business code by simply reissuing the transaction a few more times until it exits cleanly. The calling code is `synchronized` so when my application runs on a single server I have 100% guarantee that no two threads can access the method at the same time.

The same cannot be said for clustered installations. I have made myself a JUnit experiment proving that on Oracle (and perhaps Oracle only among Mysql, MS SQL and Postgres) the serialization constraint is sometimes not honoured when two threads (locking on different objects) perform the same transaction at once.

From a `SERIALIZABLE` isolation event I expect that if two transactions run at the same time either one of them is queued* or one of them is canceled, especially after the first did the SELECT. From textbook, given T1 and T2 the following must be guaranteed to be impossible

```
T1: SELECT
T2: SELECT
T2: INSERT
T1: INSERT
T1: COMMIT
T2: COMMIT
```

If I debug the above code and perform steps, thus manually guaranteeing the execution order of the above statements in a few seconds time, Oracle behaves as expected and I have one of the two transactions rolled back with explicit SQLException. If I retry the second transaction, I can see the first having committed and then the code returns false, as it is expected to run

```
T1: SELECT
T2: SELECT
T2: INSERT
T1: INSERT
T1: COMMIT
T2: ROLLBACK
T3: SELECT
T3: COMMIT EMPTY
```

Unfortunately, and here comes my question, I have seen that if I let JUnit run *in the wild* I get unpredictable results. Sometimes my test succeeds after returning false in one of the two threads, often no invocation returns false **and I get two rows of same process in `RUNNING` status inserted**. The result is not predictable, e.g. happens randomly approximately on a 50/50 odds. I can also see the database containing two rows of the process, more than having JUnit assert that only one thread returned with a false

The last violates my application constraints.

Here is a log of Show SQL output in wrong case

```
Hibernate: delete from PROCESS_RUNS
Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from PROCESS_RUNS this_ where this_.PROCESS_ID=? and this_.STATUS=?
Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from PROCESS_RUNS this_ where this_.PROCESS_ID=? and this_.STATUS=?
Hibernate: insert into PROCESS_RUNS (CONTEXT_CLASS, END_TIME, QUEUE_TIME, ESTIMATED_QUEUE_WAIT, EXCEPTION_CLASS, MODULE_ID, NODE_ID, ORGANIZATION_ID, PRIORITY, PROCESS_ID, REFERENCE_ID, START_TIME, STATUS, TRIGGER_ID, TRIGGER_TYPE, USER_ID, RUN_ID, END_CONTEXT, EXECUTION_EXCEPTION, START_CONTEXT, TRIGGER_CONTEXT) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into PROCESS_RUNS (CONTEXT_CLASS, END_TIME, QUEUE_TIME, ESTIMATED_QUEUE_WAIT, EXCEPTION_CLASS, MODULE_ID, NODE_ID, ORGANIZATION_ID, PRIORITY, PROCESS_ID, REFERENCE_ID, START_TIME, STATUS, TRIGGER_ID, TRIGGER_TYPE, USER_ID, RUN_ID, END_CONTEXT, EXECUTION_EXCEPTION, START_CONTEXT, TRIGGER_CONTEXT) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Correct case

```
Hibernate: delete from PROCESS_RUNS
Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from PROCESS_RUNS this_ where this_.PROCESS_ID=? and this_.STATUS=?
Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from PROCESS_RUNS this_ where this_.PROCESS_ID=? and this_.STATUS=?
Hibernate: insert into PROCESS_RUNS (CONTEXT_CLASS, END_TIME, QUEUE_TIME, ESTIMATED_QUEUE_WAIT, EXCEPTION_CLASS, MODULE_ID, NODE_ID, ORGANIZATION_ID, PRIORITY, PROCESS_ID, REFERENCE_ID, START_TIME, STATUS, TRIGGER_ID, TRIGGER_TYPE, USER_ID, RUN_ID, END_CONTEXT, EXECUTION_EXCEPTION, START_CONTEXT, TRIGGER_CONTEXT) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into PROCESS_RUNS (CONTEXT_CLASS, END_TIME, QUEUE_TIME, ESTIMATED_QUEUE_WAIT, EXCEPTION_CLASS, MODULE_ID, NODE_ID, ORGANIZATION_ID, PRIORITY, PROCESS_ID, REFERENCE_ID, START_TIME, STATUS, TRIGGER_ID, TRIGGER_TYPE, USER_ID, RUN_ID, END_CONTEXT, EXECUTION_EXCEPTION, START_CONTEXT, TRIGGER_CONTEXT) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
14:47:25.441 [pool-2-thread-2] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-08177: impossibile serializzare l'accesso per questa transazione

14:47:25.451 [pool-2-thread-2] ERROR org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [could not execute statement]
Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from PROCESS_RUNS this_ where this_.PROCESS_ID=? and this_.STATUS=?
```

I have talked to my team and we discussed about row locking, but in a COUNT statement there is actually no row to lock.

I have tried to amend my code a few times:

- Adding a 100ms sleep after the SELECT seems to give consistency to the wrong behaviour (i.e. I am always getting no false from threads and two rows in DBeaver).
- Re-issuing the COUNT query after INSERT to check that there is exactly one row in RUNNING status adds nothing
- Removing sleep keeps error consistent
- Changing isolation level to READ_UNCOMMITTED requires altering the entire session, possibly with devastating effects
- Changing isolation to READ_COMMITTED is not what I want in my case

I don't know what else to try. I need to fix this by either Java code or Hibernate configuration. I am also required that works with Oracle works also for MS SQL, Mysql and Postgres

**Question is**: how do I make sure that my code inserts a new row in a table if and only if no other row of the same PROCESS_ID is in status `RUNNING`, with regards to Oracle 12c and transactional isolation?

- It has been repeatedly remarked that in reality no database *serializes* transactions, but rather grants that if both succeed the result of the operation is consistent with serial execution

---

Edit 1: perhaps Oracle is working as Oracle is designed. If you see the transaction from the SQL point of view, you see only two `SELECT`s and then two `INSERT`s running on different data. The outcome of a SELECT does not change the system state, none of the results of the SELECT are used in a `VALUE` of the `INSERT`. So the outcome of serial execution is two inserts. The real problem, which other databases correctly enforce, is that the result of `SELECT` is used by caller code to take a decision on whether or not to perform `INSERT`, and that is something Oracle DB will never be able to know in advance. I remember my DB2 classes (namely `Data Bases 2nd`, not IBM DB2) where a similar issue was discussed about implementation of DBMSes

The above is likely to be true according to [research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19943305/471213) (emphasis kept)

> Oracle Database permits a serializable transaction to **modify a row only if changes to the row made by other transactions were already committed when the serializable transaction began**. The database generates an error when a serializable transaction tries to update or delete data changed by a different transaction that committed after the serializable transaction began:

Comment: `given column PROCESS_ID, only one instance of each process may be in RUNNING status` - why don't  you just create unique constraint on `(process_id, status='RUNNING')`  ? In this way the database doesn't allow for two records with the same ID and status='RUNNING` and you don't need to serialize transaction and do not need to do such complicated and tricky  synchronization taksk, just catch `DUPLICATE EXCEPTION` in your code.

Comment: *Just* is too simple. For design policy, structures have to be replicated to all four databases as they are, i.e. we don't adopt database-specific facilities for sake of testability and portability. Our **products** are installed at multiple locations. The problem of product vs project is that the project is a simple instance you can customize and optimize the way you like. Adopting DB-specific structures makes testing more complex and is currently forbidden here. I am looking for a different solution for now, sorry.

Comment: Instead of sleeping for 100 ms, how about sleeping for random x ms, and doing a check again. 
Might help with your chances for not getting a duplicate. 

Alternatively you can do a 2 step approach. 
Create a staging process table with primary key [all db have PK] process id. 
At any given time only 1 process id can be inserted in this table & other's will get a `DUPLICATE EXCEPTION`.In the step 2 phase if the record get's inserted in this staging table you move to the main txn table. Also you need to delete this record once you update that process to `STOPPED`/`OK` in the main txn table.

Comment: A better design approach would be to use the staging process table as main process table [with process id as PK] & keep the old one as history for the sake of process uniqueness. A table level PK guarantee's it. So once process finishes you move it to history & done.

Comment: I like the staging idea a lot. However, I am eager to **understand** why doesn't Oracle honour the serialization constraint, especially if on a random basis. Everyone here would be happy if Oracle threw error ORA-08177 consistently rather than changing the design of the process engine (to be redesigned in 2018 for other reasons)

Comment: Well, I think there is a gap in understanding what `Serializable` transaction does in oracle. Maybe @krokodilko can help us understand better here.

Comment: @pOrinG see my edit. I start to think that Oracle is designed to allow multiple inserts despite my idea of transaction

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ Aah. Thanks, I think that solves the doubt !!

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ yes, this is explained in the excerpt from documentation you have appended to the question: `The database generates an error when a serializable transaction tries to update or delete data changed by a different transaction that committed after the serializable transaction began` - ORA-08177: `Cannot serialize access for this transaction` is thrown when the serializable transaction tries to update or delete only, **but not INSERT**. So, Oracle allows multile inserts in the serializable isolation mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is simply how Oracle is designed. My scenatio is a `WONTFIX/WORKSASEXPECTED` case. Let me describe why.

While we agree that from a high-level point of view, the actual outcome is **not** equivalent to any sequential execution, simply Oracle is unaware of that.

In the comments, we already highlighted that Oracle guarantees isolation for `updated` and `deleted` data. Simply put...

1. Oracle has nothing to lock if `SELECT` returns no result
2. `INSERT` is not an update

I would argument that the index update would fall into the transactional protection case, but is currently out of scope.

I would also speculate that using a `sequence` would trigger the error, as the sequence is updated. But I haven't tried it. Most importantly, Hibernate caches sequence values.

## Conclusion

Protection against concurrent execution is implemented by Oracle only during `UPDATE`s and `DELETE`s. If I am not happy with that I must change database to e.g. MS SQL Server which instead offers this kind of protection.