# Multiple Threads calling same stored procedure - how to force serial execution

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, locking

We have two threads(Timer) which are calling same stored procedure in oracle. How to handle from Database side to process one thread at a time. We used **"Alter session disable Parallel DML"** query inside the Procedure, But, still both threads are running at a same time.

Is there any locking mechanism which will take care these steps ?

Expecting Result:

1. **Thread should execute the same procedure one after another.**

Can anyone suggest solution for this issue?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942521/serializable-transactions-not-protecting-me-from-double-inserts?noredirect=1#comment82858178_47942521

Comment: Oracle has several different locking mechanisms. Which one is the best for your needs depends on what your procedure actually does. So we can't give you a solution until you post more details.

Comment: "Parallel DML" doesn't refer to multiple sessions doing DML simultaneously. It is related to the mechanism for [parallelising individual SQL statements](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-2627DC19-7EBE-4C45-A758-711BDB5E37EC.htm).